# Remove part of string including a specific character from a string using MySQL

Tags: mysql, substring

```
STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO
```

I need to remove the  characters left to

```
'\'
```

and the result should be

```
HYUUM.ROOOO
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the it :)

```
select employee_id,emp_email,SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_name, '\\', -1) 
from employee_master
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) :

```
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)
```

> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

In your example, str is 'STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO'. Be careful with '\', it must be escaped because it's a special character. To do that, replace '\' by '\\'. delim is '\\' (escaped too) and count is -1 because you want the right part of the delim.

Example :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+-------------------+
| name              |
+-------------------+
| STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '\\', -1) AS foo FROM foo;
+-------------+
| foo         |
+-------------+
| HYUUM.ROOOO |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or, a simpler example :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('STACK\\HYUUM.ROOOO', '\\', -1);
```

**Don't forget to escape the backslash in 'STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO'.**

Comment: You are right. But when we give SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO', '\\', -1)  like this the result is STACKHYUUM.ROOOO

Comment: @jennifer When the value exists on the database, the '\' is already escaped. if you do this like your comment, you must escape the '\'. You have to replace SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO', '\\', -1) by SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('STACK\\HYUUM.ROOOO', '\\', -1) (see the backslash).

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
 SUBSTRING_INDEX('STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO', '\\', -1)
```

Comment: when i give 
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO', '\\', -1) ; i got STACKHYUUM.ROOOO. i need 
 HYUUM.ROOOO

Comment: but when i select a column name by giving select SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_name, '\\', -1)  from employee_master .. It works

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE('STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO','\\','');
```

ups mistake. I'll try to find solution.

Comment: This combined with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to match everything left of \ should work out. EDIT: Come to think of it, it might be the whole solution :-P

Comment: i give select REPLACE('STACK\HYUUM.ROOOO','\\','');  the ouput is STACKHYUUM.ROOOO

Comment: yes I know I'm trying to find solution. I thought you needed to replace only a backslash =)