# remove last character if it is not number

Tags: mysql

I would like to remove last character of string if is not a number.

Input column
atg167d
atg645
msc587f
atg6692

Output column
atg167
atg645
msc587
atg6692

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551272/to-remove-a-character-from-a-string-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTR(inputColumn, -1)` to get the last character, and then check to see if it's between '0' and '9'. If it is, the column ends with a number. If not, use `SUBSTR` to remove the last character:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(inCol, -1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN inCol
    ELSE SUBSTR(inCol, 1, LENGTH(inCol) - 1)
    END AS outCol
FROM myTable
```

There's a working SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c03ce/3)