# Remove charectors from mysql column

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in my MySql table: id and name.

```
id     

A.100

A.200

BA.201
```

I want to remove dots (`.`) from the id column and replace the remains (A100,A200,BA201) and store.

Comment: What language are you using to access and modify the databases?

Comment: java,any manual query

Comment: What do you have until know?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To remove a character from a string in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551272/to-remove-a-character-from-a-string-in-mysql)

Comment: i cant see any update replace answers there.

Comment: @Juan, please edit more than just a typo if you are going to edit something.

Answer (score 3):

That could be done with one update command and you already mentioned the function name into the question `replace`

```
update table_name set id = replace(id,'.','');
```